# append tableview cell int to a array

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, append

i want my swift code to append all of the ints displayed in each label of the tableview cell. So in the array it should containt 0,1,2.  The array is declared as someArray with a int value. Do the appending in func view did load. I don't know what to put it within the parentheses with append. I dont know what else code to add

```
import UIKit
 
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
 
    var numberOfRows = 3
    var someArray = [Int]()
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { numberOfRows }
 
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { 118 }
 
    var tableView = UITableView()
    var selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
 
 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 
     setTableVIew()
        someArray.append(c)
      
    }
 
 
 
    func setTableVIew(){
    
          
         
       
        
        let VCframe = view.frame
        let height = VCframe.height * 0.8
           
        let widthx = VCframe.width
 
   
             tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: widthx - 20, height: height)
          
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(tableView)
  
      
        tableView.register(customtv.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
 
 
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! customtv
       cell.lbl.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    
 
       return cell
   }
 
 
 
    
}
class customtv: UITableViewCell {
    lazy var backView : UIView = {
      let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 6, width: self.frame.width  , height: 110))
      view.backgroundColor = .green
      print(self.frame.width)
          return view
      }()
      
 
      
      override func layoutSubviews() {
         backView.clipsToBounds = true
         backView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 6, width: bounds.maxX  , height: 110)
   
 
      }
    lazy var lbl : UILabel = {
        let press = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 3, width: 120 , height: 50))
        press.backgroundColor = .yellow
        press.text = String("1")
            
        return press
    }()
 
   
 
 
 
 
 
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(animated, animated: true)
        addSubview(backView)
    
        backView.addSubview(lbl)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `var someArray = [0, 1, 2]`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson no I want the array to append the values from the table into that array. The number from the tableview would be 0  1 2

Comment: But what does it matter if the values are always 0, 1, 2 how you initialise/append your array with them?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The values would not always be 012 they are just the first 3 numbers on the tableview label cells. I just want to take the first 3 numbers whatever they are from the tableview cells.

Comment: Those values must come from somewhere, why don't you get them from the source?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don’t know how to get them from the source meaning you mean the table view source you would show me that be great

Comment: All I see is this, `cell.lbl.text = "\(indexPath.row)` but is that all you have in your table view? I can't know what your data is, you need to know that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
for c in 0...117 {
    someArray.append(c)
}
```

Comment: How does this connect to the tableview